# Cython syntax for declaring class hierarchies that have aliases

Tags: python, c++, cython

Here is an abstract base class and a concrete subclass, which I would like to expose to Python via Cython:

```
class NodeDistance {

protected:
    const Graph& G;

public:
    NodeDistance(const Graph& G);
    virtual ~NodeDistance();
    virtual void preprocess() = 0;
    virtual double distance(node u, node v) = 0;
};


class NeighborhoodDistance: public NetworKit::NodeDistance {

public:
    NeighborhoodDistance(const Graph& G);
    virtual ~NeighborhoodDistance();
    virtual void preprocess();
    virtual double distance(node u, node v);
};
```

This is my first attempt at declaring the interface of the classes for Cython. To avoid naming conflicts between the `cppclass`es and the Python wrapper classes, I declare every `Class` as `_Class`, followed by its proper name `"Namespace::Class"`.

```
cdef extern from "../cpp/distmeasures/NodeDistance.h":
    cdef cppclass _NodeDistance "NetworKit::NodeDistance":
        _NodeDistance(_Graph G) except +
        void preprocess() except +
        double distance(node, node) except +


cdef extern from "../cpp/distmeasures/NeighborhoodDistance.h":
    cdef cppclass _NeighborhoodDistance(_NodeDistance) "NetworKit::NeighborhoodDistance":
        _NeighborhoodDistance(_Graph G) except +
        void preprocess() except +
        double distance(node, node) except +
```

But now I get a syntax error when trying to express that `_NeighborhoodDistance` is a subclass of `_NodeDistance`. What did I do wrong?

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        void preprocess() except +
        double distance(node, node) except +


cdef extern from "../cpp/distmeasures/NeighborhoodDistance.h":
    cdef cppclass _NeighborhoodDistance(_NodeDistance) "NetworKit::NeighborhoodDistance":
                                                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

_NetworKit.pyx:1698:52: Syntax error in C++ class definition
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can even express the combination of base class and renaming in Cython 0.20.1. You can either not rename the classes and specify the namespace in the `cdef extern from`:

```
# C++ classes shown at the end
cdef extern from "example.hpp" namespace "example":
    cdef cppclass Base:
        void some_method() except +

    cdef cppclass Derived(Base):
        void some_method() except +
```

... or not specify the inheritance:

```
cdef extern from "example.hpp" namespace "example":
    cdef cppclass Base "example::Base":
        void some_method() except +

    cdef cppclass Derived "example::Derived":
        void some_method() except +
```

Either way, Cython doesn't seem to understand C++ inheritance fully, and you need an explicit cast:

```
def test():
    cdef Derived d
    cdef Base *p = <Base *>&d
    p.some_method()
```

This is ugly because the cast effectively turns off typechecking in C++, but with care it can be used safely. (There are other circumstances where Cython's typechecking requires casts that are not necessary in C/C++, which is quite unfortunate.)

For reference, here are the classes I used:

```
// example.hpp
#include <cstdio>

namespace example {
    struct Base {
        virtual void some_method() = 0;
        virtual ~Base() = 0;
    };

    struct Derived {
        virtual void some_method()
        {
            std::puts("Hello!");
        }
        ~Derived()
        {
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: ["As a special bonus, any reputation you earn from being awarded a bounty is exempt from the daily reputation cap."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. A pity that Cython practically does not support inheritance, polymorphism and such nice things.